# C# - Get all app reviews in PlayStore

Tags: c#, google-analytics, proxy, google-api, google-play

I want to create a Solution to get all app reviews in PlayStore, but I don't know how to do it. I have a code for connecting to Google Analytics, but I've a lot of errors when I ran it.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace Google_api
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var filepath = "...";  // path to the json file for the Service account
                var viewid = "..."; // ID to access your view in G.A

                GoogleCredential credentials;

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    string[] scopes = { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };
                    var googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
                    credentials = googleCredential.CreateScoped(scopes);
                }

                var reportingService = new AnalyticsReportingService(
                    new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credentials
                    });

                var dateRange = new DateRange
                {
                    StartDate = "2017-05-01",
                    EndDate = "2017-05-31"
                };

                var sessions = new Metric
                {
                    Expression = "ga:sessions",
                    Alias = "Sessions"
                };

                var date = new Dimension { Name = "ga:date" };

                var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
                {
                    DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
                    Dimensions = new List<Dimension> { date },
                    Metrics = new List<Metric> { sessions },
                    ViewId = viewid
                };

                var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest
                {
                    ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest }
                };

                var batchRequest = reportingService.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);
                var response = batchRequest.Execute();
                foreach (var x in response.Reports.First().Data.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", x.Dimensions) + "   " + string.Join(", ", x.Metrics.First().Values));
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've received this error:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy'
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Invalid argument supplied in
>   System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent.CreateWSASocketWithEvent(AddressFamily
>   addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType,
>   Boolean autoReset, Boolean signaled)   in
>   System.Net.NetworkAddressChangePolled..ctor()   in
>   System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.AutoDetector.Initialize()   in
>   System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.AutoDetector.get_CurrentAutoDetector()
>   in System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine..ctor(WebProxy proxy, Boolean
>   useRegistry)   in System.Net.WebProxy.UnsafeUpdateFromRegistry()   in
>   System.Net.WebProxy..ctor(Boolean enableAutoproxy)   in
>   System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal..ctor(DefaultProxySection
>   section) in
>   System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSection() --
>   --- End of internal exception stack trace ---
>       in Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest'1.Execute()
>       in Google_api.Program.Main(String[] args) na X:\example\Program.cs:line 64

I'll create a metric to catch all reviews in PlayStore with the GA. Is this possible? In case not, can you help me? I want to catch all the reviews in PlayStore and all the information of devices that rated my app. The Reviews API return only information about those that commented. If anyone could provide some sample code or point me in the right direction to get some basic report data using the .net API, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! (And sorry for my bad English...)

Comment: you have access to google play store? If so use https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export and gsutil to access them programmatically

Comment: I don't has permission to install softwares in my computer and I've access to a google play store. The .NET API not has code examples to get reviews informations, someone could to help me?